# Unit Tests not showing in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, automated-tests

I've built an automation framework in VS and have roughly 25 Unit Tests. These files have been showing and running fine for about a year now. However, a few days ago, all of the tests have stopped showing in the Test Explorer. The five .ordertest that I have in the project show just fine, they even run the Unit Tests that aren't showing when I run them. I have tried cleaning the build, rebuilding, closing / opening, pulling an older version from my repository, switching architecture in the test panel, etc.

At this point I'm at a loss and really need some help. Thanks!

Comment: If the answers in the marked duplicates do not help you then please update your question with **all** the relevant details including what you have tried up to this point and write back to me directly in the comments. I can then re-open your question.

Comment: Hard to say. Which Test framework, which (test related) plugins and do mention the version of everything. Even VS2017 has seen many releases.

Comment: I just realized that I needed to update Visual Studio. My bad people!